# Ambiguous use of init in Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm getting an "ambiguous use of init" error when building with Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2

The issue is related to two Objective-C classes and how Swift views their initializers.

Objc sees:

*Superclass*

```
@interface Foo: NSManagedObject
+(instancetype)fooWithOwner:(Owner *)owner insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
```

*Subclass*

```
@interface Bar: Foo
+(instancetype)barWithOwner:(Owner *)owner insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
```

while Swift only sees:

```
init(owner: Owner!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!)
```

which is causing the compiler to be unsure of which init is being called on the subclass "Bar". Is there a way to specify which initializer to use when initializing the subclass? I'd like to avoid refactoring the init method if possible.

Comment: You can rename to `makeFooWithOwner...` and `makeBarWithOwner...` or something similar and it won't convert them to initializers

Comment: Can you post the Swift code that you're having the problem with? I copy/pasted into a new project and didn't have any trouble compiling.

Comment: there is no reason why the original Obj-C methods should have different names in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is due to [ObjC->Swift API translation rules](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md).

You can use `swift_name` attribute to overwrite these rules.

```
@interface Foo: NSManagedObject
+(instancetype)fooWithOwner:(Owner *)owner insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context NS_SWIFT_NAME(foo(owner:moc:));

@interface Bar: Foo
+(instancetype)barWithOwner:(Owner *)owner insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context NS_SWIFT_NAME(bar(owner:moc:));
```

Then you can call them separately in Swift code:

```
let foo = Bar.foo(owner: owner, moc: context)
let bar = Bar.bar(owner: owner, moc: context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on, btw I tried this. In the ObjC header I added those two class methods:

```
+ (id)barWithInitializer:(NSString *)className
 initializer:(SEL)initializer
    argument:(id)argument;

+ (id)fooWithInitializer:(NSString *)className
                initializer:(SEL)initializer
                   argument:(id)argument;
```

Then in the Swift function

I have tried both with no issue / interface mismatch

```
return OBJCObjectFactory.barWithInitializer(className, initializer: initializer, argument: argument) as! TBase?

return OBJCObjectFactory.fooWithInitializer(className, initializer: initializer, argument: argument) as! TBase?
```